# Finding maximum and minimum value from a field

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a temp table ttsales which contains a field name t_sales of integer type, I want to find out the maximum and minimum value from a t_sales And on a button click those maximum and minimum value will show. what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
DEFINE QUERY qry FOR tsales.

OPEN QUERY qry FOR EACH tsales BY t_sales.

GET FIRST qry.

MESSAGE tsales.t_sales.

GET LAST qry.

MESSAGE tsales.t_sales.
```

Depending on size of table, add an index on the field.

Comment: Can I do it using break by or aggregate function?

Comment: @user13418366 Break by wont gain you anything in this case

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to sort the temp-table in ascending and descending order. Adding an index will help. If you cant change the temp-table and its large this might not be the best solution.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttsales NO-UNDO
    FIELD t_sales AS INTEGER
    INDEX sales t_sales.

DEFINE VARIABLE iMin AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iMax AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

CREATE ttsales.
ASSIGN ttsales.t_sales = 10.

CREATE ttsales.
ASSIGN ttsales.t_sales = 1.

CREATE ttsales.
ASSIGN ttsales.t_sales = 130.

CREATE ttsales.
ASSIGN ttsales.t_sales = 2.

/* Get minimum value */
FOR EACH ttsales BY ttsales.t_sales:
    iMin = ttsales.t_sales.
    LEAVE.
END.

/* Get maximum value */    
FOR EACH ttsales BY ttsales.t_sales DESCENDING:
    iMax = ttsales.t_sales.
    LEAVE.
END.

DISPLAY iMin iMax.
```